# How to remove second level index from associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

print_r($unique_id);

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [LeadEmailDetail] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 97
                    [email] => vikastyagismartbuzz8@gmail.com
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [LeadEmailDetail] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 93
                    [email] => vikastyagi87@gmail.com
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [LeadEmailDetail] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 94
                    [email] => vikastyagismartbuzz9@gmail.com
                )
        )

)
```

But i want like that

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 97
            [email] => vikastyagismartbuzz8@gmail.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 93
            [email] => vikastyagi87@gmail.com
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 94
            [email] => vikastyagismartbuzz9@gmail.com
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
array_map('array_shift', $unique_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
foreach($unique_id as $k => $v)
{
    $array[] = array_shift($v);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple loop does a job for you:

```php
foreach ($array as &$v) {
    $v = current($v);
}
unset($v);
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/210396)</kbd>

<sub>p.s. doesn't create another array (memory leak) like other examples.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

`print_r( array_column( $unique_id, 'LeadEmailDetail' ) );`

Requires PHP >=  5.5.0

Comment: A second this answer, but it should be noted that this requires `php>=5.5`.

Answer (score 0):

Who build the **$unique_id** array? I would recommend to build it in the form you like

To solve your question ... out of the box quick and dirty

```
<?php
    $new = array();
    foreach($unique_id as $arr) {
       foreach ($arr['LeadEmailDetail'] as $a) {
         $new[] = $a;
       }
    }
    print_r($new);
```